# how to dismiss the popover with the bar button click

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uipopovercontroller

Hey  there I have an in which I had to show the popover. I could easily do this. When popover of other class is shown. There is titlebar with a bar button "Done" in this popover. I want to dismiss the popover with click of done button.

how can i dismiss the popover with done button?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you tried to search for the solution?

```
-(void) onDoneButtonClick {
    [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks George I tried this UIPopoverController* popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]init];

    if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }     but it crashes giving error        -[UIPopoverController init] is not a valid initializer. You must call -[UIPopoverController initWithContentViewController:].'

Answer (score 0):

`- (void)dismissPopoverAnimated:(BOOL)animated` is a method of `UIPopoverController` class. In order to dismiss a popover programatically you have to keep a reference to the presented `UIPopoverController` yourself.

Here is a possible solution:

In the view controller that popover loads, define a property.

```
@interface MyViewController: UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popover;

@end
```

Before segue to popover is performed, store segue's popover controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"mySegue"]) 
    {
        MyViewController *dvc = segue.destinationViewController;
        dvc.popover = [segue popoverController];
    }
}
```

When the button clicked, dismiss popover.

```
- (void)onButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In simply popoverobj and use the simply method on button event.

```
   [popoverobj dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```